# what is AWS Lightsail bucket for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, upload, amazon-lightsail

I am new to server stuff.
I'd like to store some images on the server (willing to use Amazon lightsail) and
load those images from a mobile app and display them.
Can I do this with Amazon lightsail/storage/bucket and do I need to buy it?
I think I will store just a few images (probably less than 200 images, each image less than 1MB).
Not gonna upload them all at once.

I guess this is so simple question, but for beginners, it's not so simple.
Thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lightsail is AWS' easy-to-use virtual private server. Lightsail offers virtual servers, storage, databases, networking, CDN, and monitoring for a low, predictable price.

The ideia of the Lightsail service is provide an easy to you host your application without the need of handle a lot of settings.

For your case, you simple need S3 buckets to host images, I do not think that Lightsail will the best option.

Simple save your files in a S3 bucket and load the images using presigned/public URLs, or via the SDK.

For more information about the Lightsail service take a look here: [What can I do with Lightsail?](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/#:%7E:text=Common%20use%20cases%20for%20Lightsail,%2C%20simple%20software%2C%20and%20more.)